# Mask subdomain.mydomain1.com to subdomain.mydomain2.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, mask

I have got customer.mydomain1.com and want to mask it to customer.mydomain2.com

so that customer.mydomain1.com shows content of customer.mydomain2.com and url stays the same as of customer.mydomain1.com

I am using the code below used in my .htaccess, which gives me ERROR 400

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^customer.mydomain1.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://customer.mydomain2.com/$1 [P]
```

Comment: Are both sites on the same Server? If not you only can do a redirect. If yes, you also need access to your apache config. Do you have it?

Comment: @Webdesigner yes both of them are on same server. yes i do have apache config access! How to fix it?

Comment: Why not add customer.mydomain1.com as a ServerAlias to your Vitualhost of customer.mydomain2.com so if you call customer.mydomain1.com you get content of customer.mydomain2.com and disable virtual host from customer.mydomain1.com

Comment: @Webdesigner i tried gave me Error 500

Comment: What dose your log files say about the error? Please give us a little bit more information. Without it is a little bit hard for us. Read the doumentaion: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#ServerAlias

Comment: The [P] Flag requires that mod_proxy is enabled... but IMHO ServerAlias is  what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a ServerAlias this works for any domain that have an A-Record or a CNAME pointing to your server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName customer.mydomain2.com
    ServerAlias www.customer.mydomain2.com customer.mydomain1.com example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/path/to/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

No need to use mod_rewite with mod_proxy (required for the the [P] Flag)
All listed domains (you can add as many you like)

- customer.mydomain2.com
- www.customer.mydomain2.com
- customer.mydomain1.com
- example.com

will respond with the content of `/var/www/path/to/public_html` so just replace it with the public directory of your customer.mydomain2.com server.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong in your config.  I used this configuration on my local apache, so both domains are on the same HTTPD:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName customer.mydomain1.com
    ErrorLog "logs/error_mydomain1_log"
    CustomLog "logs/access_mydomain1_log" common

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^customer.mydomain1.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://customer.mydomain2.com/$1 [P]

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName customer.mydomain2.com
    ErrorLog "logs/error_mydomain2_log"
    CustomLog "logs/access_mydomain2_log" common

    DocumentRoot "/home/tools/apache/htdocs/mydomain2"
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</VirtualHost>
```

Then changed my local hosts file to define both domains, and it works. I get the content of index.html if I access http://customer.mydomain1.com.  I also created other files, in sub-directories on customer.mydomain2.com and when I access them, customer.mydomain1.com stays in the address bar.

So either there is something in your configuration, or some module is missing.  Does $(apachectl -t) return "Syntax OK"?  Did you restart your apache?