# How to point a domain to dynamic subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, dns

At the moment, I have a service which requires **dynamic sub-domains** which is implanted and working as expected, now, after the user gets the sub domains, what I want to do is, giving the user the ability to connect `their own` domain name to the sub domain that I have provided.

For example :

This is the user `danny` with url :

`danny.example.com`

so, right now everything works as expected, the next thing for the user would be purchasing a domain name and point it to `danny.example.com`

So here is where i'm stuck.

Here, I want to give the user the ability to set dns's to his/her domain

`ns1.example.com`

`ns2.example.com`

and then, what i expect is, it resolves the main domain (`example.com`), then i check the domain name which is provided by the user `danny`, lets say the domain name is `danny.com`, then if the `danny.com` matched with the one that user `danny` has submitted as his domain name in `example.com`, then the process continues and the `danny.example.com` content shows up.

so the shorter version of what i want is :

point the `sample.example.com` to `sample.com` with the exact same content

btw, at the moment I've been trying to use a free domain name `.cf` for tests

i have thoroughly searched about this and i'm really frustrated with it since i couldn't find the "right" solution for it for weeks.

---- UPDATE ----

the blogger is a good example of what i want.

---- UPDATE 2 ----

The server which i am using is a shared host which runs on apache

I have `CNAME` Records for the following addresses :

`mail.mysite.com`

`www.mysite.com`

And of course, the wildcard

`*.mysite.com`

Answer (score 0):

I see two separate issue here:

1) Pointing one (or more) Fully-Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) to your server.
2) Showing the right site.

Regarding the first Point I would not force a user to use your NS because if the user has already one domain and only wants to link a sub-domain to your server, than I would just give the user an instruction what he should do, e.g. setting his own FQDN with a CNAME to his personal service domain (e.g. danny.example.com).
CNAME is better than an A-Record because if you have to change your IP, all user have to change them as well.
On the other hand, if you really want to provide a NS you should have a solution where the user can manage the hole domain settings, because the user maybe wants to add a mail server (MX record) or some other sub-domains that have nothing to do with your service.

Lets say the first point is solved so the users FQDN pointing to your server, then you only have to show the same web-space/site as with your own sub-domain (e.g. danny.example.com). This is nothing you can solve with a htaccess file but very easy in you Virtualhost configuration. For Apache just like so:
[Mask subdomain.mydomain1.com to subdomain.mydomain2.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469497/mask-subdomain-mydomain1-com-to-subdomain-mydomain2-com/46503132#46503132)

On nginx this works similar: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Because you did not provide any details what exact Software you are use I can only give a general overview. All those things could be scripted in one way or the other, but this is a off topic (open up a new question if not exist already).

Comment: Thank you for your response @webdesigner.
I'm sorry about the lack of information on the sever which i am using, the question is updated now and the server is running on a shared host with apache, about the first issue, i would like to make it as easy as possible for my client ( like the `CNAME` ), Could you please give more information about the usage of CNAME, because I really don't have enough information in this area

Comment: If you could please put me in the right direction on the usage of `CNAME` i would be really grateful, the access on the apache configurations are highly restricted but i do have access to `Zone Editor(s)`, so what do i need to do in order to achieve what i need ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record explains in general what a CNAME is. How your users have to add one really depends on the hoster where they bought the domain.